# Germany City Registration with wrong address

Tags: germany, rental

I moved to another town for a new job. It is very hard to find a new apartment in another town. I saw a shared room on video and signed the contract.

After moving to a new town, the landlord has provided another room in a different address. Example Address in Contract is Street 1, however, the room is in Street 1A.

I did my city registration with Address Street 1 only. I believe the owner is renting this building illegally but not sure.

These are 2 different buildings on the same piece of land by the same owner. 
I did not pay any attention at the start (again find a new apartment/room immediately at the start of a new job) however I am now worried. It's been more than 3 months. What will be the legal consequences for me?  Can I inform the Rathaus about the same?

Did anyone have any experience?

Comment: Were you in the different building when you registered?  What did the Einzugsbestätigung that the owner gave you state? Is this only a 'A' missing from the address house number?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the administration where you registered after you had moved in and tell them about the change. If you have a rental agreement with the correct address, take it with you.

If you do this as soon as possible, the legal consequences will not be harsh. Perhaps you have to pay a small fine because you waited for so long, but perhaps nothing happens at all. Especially if you are able to explain your behavior, that you were busy with a job search etc.

If you do not tell them and they find out, the consequences will be much worse.